# How to assign headers and use the request body in angular 4 PUT request?

Tags: angular, httpclient, response, put

I am trying to upload a csv file using the HttpClient of angular 4 using the PUT request. The headers accepted is application/octet-stream.

My http put request is as below :

```
public uploadFileToDm(uploadUrl,file): any {
    return this.http.put(uploadUrl,file,{ headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream' }) }).
    map((response: Response) => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log("confirm");
      } else {
        return Observable.throw(uploadUrl + 'upload failed:' + response.status);
      }
    }).catch((error: Response) => {
      console.log('Error occured while getting upload urls.' + error);
      return Observable.throw(error);
    });
  }
```

How can i get the response code and status?

Comment: `https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#!#sts=Put` refer this

Answer (score 0):

The place where you subscribe to the event. move the code inside `map` operator to `subscribe`

```
this.uploadFileToDm().subscribe(data => {
  if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log("confirm");
      } else {
        return Observable.throw(uploadUrl + 'upload failed:' + response.status);
      }
})
```

Comment: I cant do that, since i need to make another service call after i get the response from this particular url. Basically, is status 200 then i need to call antoher service.

Comment: But anyway you need to subscribe to the observable in order to send the req. so why not call the other req inside the subscribe

Comment: it doesnt work like that too since the next service call depends on this status code